# How to set path in environment variables when installing packages in Atom?

Tags: c++, atom-editor, mingw-w64

I am trying to install a package in Atom. No matter which package, I get the same error.

> spawn C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe ENOENT

[This is the error message from the command line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NhqW3.jpg)

I do have in path variables ComSpec %SystemRoot%\system32\cmd.exe

[This is my System Variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R1R6u.jpg)

.atom path is C:\Users\ucbil.atom

Atom path is C:\Users\ucbil\AppData\Local\atom

Comment: Does it make a difference when you try this as a normal user (not admin)?

Comment: @idleberg No, I have tried either way. It just won't work.